# Add a space between ul and li element created by JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Been struggling with a problem now.

I have a list that behaves quite weird, and couldt find the problem until i firebugd it and saw that the entire file prints out in one row.

something like this.

```
<div class="clock-content-wrapper"><ul class="clock-digit-wrapper hour"><li class="clock-digit-one"></li><li class="clock-digit-three"></li></ul><ul class="clock-digit-wrapper minute"><li class="clock-digit-three"></li><li class="clock-digit-seven"></li></ul><ul class="clock-digit-wrapper second"><li class="clock-digit-zero"></li><li class="clock-digit-zero"></li></ul></div>
```

There is no spaces between the elements.

Now i didn't know that could be a problem so i started to fix the elements in firebug like this.

```
<div class="clock-content-wrapper">
<ul class="clock-digit-wrapper hour">
<li class="clock-digit-one"></li>
<li class="clock-digit-three"></li>
</ul>
<ul class="clock-digit-wrapper minute">
<li class="clock-digit-three"></li>
<li class="clock-digit-seven"></li>
</ul>
<ul class="clock-digit-wrapper second">
<li class="clock-digit-zero"></li>
<li class="clock-digit-zero"></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

And notice that if i have the `</ul>` element under my `</li>` the script actually works at it supposed to.

Is there a way to structure the file with javascript ?
I have a jsFiddle, where you can se the differens between the tree created in HTML and the one with JavaScript. 
http://jsfiddle.net/Xk49c/

I really dont want to change anything in the css . since both html and js application is using the same css .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, when you create the elements using HTML, you indent or separate the elements with one or more spaces, or even new lines. HTML renders these spaces as ONE single space and so you see the space between those elements.

To add spaces between elements created by JavaScript, either you ll have to add a padding left to `minute` and `second` class, or insert a text node between each `UL`

```
hours = createElementWithClass('ul', 'clock-digit-wrapper hour');
clock_toolbar_wrapper_close.appendChild(hours);
clock_toolbar_wrapper_close.appendChild(document.createTextNode(' ')); // Add this


minutes = createElementWithClass('ul', 'clock-digit-wrapper minute');
clock_toolbar_wrapper_close.appendChild(minutes);
clock_toolbar_wrapper_close.appendChild(document.createTextNode(' ')); // And this
```

Comment: I saw you post in the other question i had, thanks. I did acctually try the textNode between the UL but the result was that it putted down the class like a <p> tag. so the image got displaced.

Comment: Oh. I didn't se your post, just the comment. omg. Its working i created the textNode in a different way, was probably that.. I'm quite noob :)
But thank you so much.

Answer (score 4):

Your `<ul>` elements are displayed as `inline-block` in your fiddle. I suspect they are suffering from [this little-known feature of `inline-block`](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/).